# Checking authentication in Laravel via Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

In my Angular app I created a service:

```
.factory('Auth', function($http) {
    return {
        is_authenticated: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/users/is_authenticated');
        }
    }
});
```

My method in my API backed by Laravel:

```
public function is_authenticated()
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return Response::json(array('authenticated' => true));
    }

    return Response::json(array('authenticated' => false));
}
```

And then in my controller:

```
    Auth.is_authenticated()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.is_authenticated = data.authenticated;
            if(data.authenticated)
                console.log('yes');
        });
```

When I go to `/api/users/is_authenticated` I see nothing on the page, however, when I echo `Auth::check()` there is a 1 on the page.

In my view I have a list with `ng-show="is_authenticated"` but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm failing to see the problem.  Why is `'yes'` not being logged to the console?

And yes, I have injected the `Auth` service into my controller.

Comment: what did you get in the console.log after success ?

Comment: execute inside the success ?

Comment: It is executed inside the success?

Comment: Try to check for error simply Auth.is_authenticated().success(function(data){}).error(function(reason){console.log(reason);})